# Is there a way to get all the tweets from a person from "yesterday" without comparing every single tweet?

Tags: python, twitter

So this is my code to get a person's timeline:

```
from tweepy import OAuthHandler
from tweepy import Cursor
from tweepy import API
import json
ckey = ''
csecret = ''
atoken = ''
asecret = ''
auth = OAuthHandler(ckey, csecret)
auth.set_access_token(atoken, asecret)
api  = API(auth)
for status in Cursor(api.user_timeline,id="mytwitterhandle").items(10):
    t = status.text.encode("ascii", "ignore")
    print status.created_at
    #check if the tweet was created yesterday
    #if so print t
```

And I was wondering, is there a way to get all the tweets a person has sent over the past day without comparing one by one?

Comment: I don't really know the API, but if there are no other options... binary search. Questionable if it would be faster though.

Comment: @TimSeguine twitter's nice enough to return me the data in chronological order, so I don't have to search anything, I can just cut off as soon as I check a tweet that's older than yesterday, but not sure if the api allowed you to do that...

Comment: Yeah, I understood; my suggestion relies on that. I am saying you can exponentially modify your id bounds(the api seems to allow this), and use the threshhold crossing information you discover to examine less posts. You have to examine only logarithmically many instead of linear, so it fits your "comparing one by one" criterion. I was only saying that network latency might erase your algorithmic efficiency gains

Comment: Ahh yeah @TimSeguine that makes sense. I'll take that into consideration if it comes down to that ;)

Comment: The only thing I see that sems remotely close to what you want in the docs seems to be this: http://docs.tweepy.org/en/v3.1.0/api.html#API.search And if it is an entry into this search api: https://dev.twitter.com/rest/public/search then it seems to allow for what you want. Would be my bet. If not you can access the rest api directly from python using http methods.

Comment: Looks like you can't do explicit time constraints (only Tweet IDs) on the [`statuses/user_timeline`](https://dev.twitter.com/rest/reference/get/statuses/user_timeline) endpoint but you *can* reference human-readable dates with `since:` and `until:` with the [search api](https://dev.twitter.com/rest/public/search), and get only a specific user with `from:` to emulate `user_timeline`. But that might be more trouble than it's worth.

Comment: @TimSeguine I'm fine with throwing out the twitter package, but not sure how I would go about doing what I need to do, other than going one by one.